# Where can I post a survey link to collect the data from Stack Overflow members?

Tags: discussion

I prepared a survey for my thesis with the focus on the usage of Stack Overflow by professional users for learning perspective.

How can I post such a survey in accordance with all rules and without being seen as a spammer?

Comment: Don't be so hasty to dismiss this, everyone!  @SalMon how much are you offering to take part in your survey and how much time do you estimate it would take?

Comment: Thank you for your advice, as I'm new in the community, I was wondering if there is a place to post a survey and volunteer members could participate in it. I believe that I'm not allowed to post a survey link here.

Comment: You should look at the questions posted and the answers given and evaluate the "learning" potential - I won't respond to a survey (except for voting moderators etc) on here as I am interested in the questions and answering them.

Comment: @Martin James the survey is short and it will take a maximum of 10 minutes

Comment: @SalMon The excuse of being new means you should take the tour and check out what types of questions are acceptable : https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364479/received-emailed-survey

Comment: @solar Mike yes I agree with you and I will do that. but at this point, I need some feedback from you as professional users on the efficiency of participating in the community in developing your skills. I'm investigating the Stack Overflow as an informal learning tool for professional developers.

Comment: @SalMon So, even though you now know surveys are not acceptable, you still want to do it....

Comment: @solar Mike no, definitely I will not post it here (at least as a survey), I have to find another way to collect my required data. I might change my method and find a proper solution for my issue

Answer (score 6):

Basically you can't. Being in accordance with the rules and posting such a question are mutually incompatible.

On Meta (i.e. here) questions have to be about Stack Overflow and on the main site they have to be [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are no host my survey sites anywhere in Stack Exchange currently.

The best you could do here would be to host the survey somewhere else, put a link to that on your profile and see if anyone sees it. That's unlikely to get you very far unless you've answered thousands of questions and people come to your profile to see who you are.

At least you've saved yourself the downvotes, close votes and deletion that go with actually doing this.

Comment: yes, you are right and thousands of answers it took me forever and I won't be graduated. Thank you for the clear response.

Answer (score 5):

This is not permitted on StackOverflow, the only way to have people answer your survey would be to contact a representative sample of target companies, asking them to distribute the survey to their employees.

Alternatively, if the data you're looking for is obtainable through SO itelf you could submit a proposal for [Stack Overflow Academic Research Partnership Program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377152/891919).

You should also check [the official SO Developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/), which might contain some of the information you want.

Comment: Thank You @Erwan, I already studied and used the data from the developer surveys  (2016-2017-2018) but as the learning perspective was not the main concern of SO surveys, I prepared a short survey with the focus on knowledge sharing and learning. but as you said it it is not permitted to post here in SO. Thank you!!