# Get the list of all flagged comments

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer, data-dump

I am trying to retrieve a list of all flagged comments on Stack Overflow. I looked up some tables on Stack Exchange Data Explorer. I found `FlagTypes` and `PendingFlags` tables. However, they seem to contain only questions that were flagged. I am specifically looking for comments, not questions. I also explored Stack Exchange Web API but couldn't find what I am looking for. One last thing. I know that some of the flagged comments might have already been deleted by the moderators. If there is no way to retrieve those flagged and subsequently deleted comments, I would at least like to get the ones flagged but not yet deleted.

Comment: "like to get the ones flagged but not yet deleted" - the only way to get those is by being a moderator.

Comment: Flagging info on comments is not public. You would need SE staff support to get them but I expect you'll need to explain better *why* you want those. An example of a similar request that got a community fed and SE staff response https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326494

Comment: @rene, yeah I had seen that thread. However, I don't necessarily need the flagged and deleted comments. Even if I can get just the flagged but not deleted comments, it's fine. I need it for research purpose.

Comment: @SamuelLiew, thank you. How do I become a moderator? Do I have to contest in an election? Or do I become a mod automatically once I get 10k points?

Comment: @VHS once you reach 10K+, you will get access to *moderator tools*, a special set of privileges, but will not become a moderator. Yes, moderators are elected in Community Moderator Elections, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/election), held from time to time when a need arises (sometimes, mods are appointed, but this is exceptional and is unlikely to happen on SO).

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine, thanks. Is getting access to "moderator tools" enough for me to see the flagged comments (deleted or undeleted)?

Comment: I don't think anyone except for SO employees and moderators (how are not allowed to share them) can see deleted comments. If you need the data for academic research, you can try to apply to the [Academic Research Partnership Program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/stack-overflow-academic-research-partnership-program). Other than that I see no way to get the information you need.

Comment: @bdl, thank you. I just applied to that program requesting the data for my research. By the way, just to confirm, I won't get access to see the deleted comments or undeleted flagged comments even if I reach 10k reputation points - is that correct?

Comment: @vhs this is correct