# Extend Stack Overflow data with external links

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I see a db/query API at https://data.stackexchange.com/, but in the schema, there aren’t any external links, like a Twitter or GitHub account.

I see historical dumps at https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/, but again, no external links in the user profile.

Is it possible to extend the schema with Twitter or GitHub?

Comment: can you elaborate your point, i can't see, what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to get info about users' external links on their profiles. A user can set up his/her Twitter or GitHub account. I'd like to have access to this info via API or in the DB dump, somehow else.

Comment: What purpose would you like this information for?

Comment: Study, research project. I agree, this is on edge

Comment: If you talk about academic research, you might want to read [Stack Overflow Academic Research Partnership Program](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/stack-overflow-academic-research-partnership-program)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335045/can-i-search-for-users-github-or-twitter-info-in-data-se

Answer (score 22):

#### Let's not make it easier to bulk scrape contact information from Stack Overflow

Stack Overflow [already had to make it a Terms-of-Service violation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277369/165261) to scrape personal information from Stack Overflow profiles, because shady companies were reading it from profile pages.  Having it in a nice, easily queryable format that can be downloaded in bulk would be a shady scraper's *dream*.

Let's not make the dreams of shady scrapers come true.

Comment: thank you, got it, now it's clear to me the reason why